# Is there a way in asp.net web api / mvc to use a context model coming from a referenced dll?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I just want to know if it is possible to use a context in asp.net web-api / mvc that was coming from a referenced DLL file. Because what I did here was that I created a separate project library for my models and wanted to used it just by adding it as a referenced to my main project. But when I created a web-api controller, and select that context coming from the referenced DLL, it gave me an error that the context is not supported.

Is this possible or not? And if it is, can someone help me with the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you post some code and the error message?

Answer (score 0):

With "context model", I suppose you're talking about an Entity Framework DbContext, right?

If so, yes, it is possible to use an EF context that is in a referenced DLL, I have this scenario working in one of my projects. Please post the error message you're getting, maybe you're forgetting some reference in the Web API project (to Entity Framework, for example).